# What is the best way to mock a java class alone with out JUNIT

Tags: mocking, mockito

i was asked to mock a java class so that testing team can test them but when i am trying to search the different types of mocking and all all i am getting is mocking along with junit

for example mockit with junit. can someone help me with out with this confusion

Comment: You need to post more information on what you are trying to do. Technically you don't need to use Mockito with JUnit, you could just as well use in production code without any trouble, but I must admit that I have never seen it done

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I would recommend you use a framework like JUnit*

However, here's a working example using Mockito that can be run as a Java Application and does not depend on JUnit.

You will require [mockito-all.jar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cmockito-all) on your class path to run this code.

This Class is testing an implementation of `Bar` that has a dependency on another class named `Foo`.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class BarTestCase {

    private Bar bar; // the class under test

    @Mock
    private Foo foo;

    public BarTestCase() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); // initialise Mockito
        bar = new BarImpl(foo);
    }

    public void testSomethingWithBar() {
        // given
        String name = "fred";

        // when
        bar.getUserByFirstName(name);

        // then
        verify(foo).doSomething(name);
        // verify(foo).doSomething("");     // un-comment this line to see the test fail
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BarTestCase myTestCase = new BarTestCase();
        myTestCase.testSomethingWithBar();
        System.out.println("SUCCESS!");
    }
}
```

These are the other classes/interfaces you will need to run the above test class

```
public interface Bar {
    void getUserByFirstName(String name);
}

public class BarImpl implements Bar {

    private Foo foo;

    public BarImpl(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    @Override
    public void getUserByFirstName(String name) {
        foo.doSomething(name);
    }
}

public interface Foo {
    void doSomething(String name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection to the rescue. You could put your implementation behind an interface and have two classes implementing it. One for the actual production code and one for test purposes. To decide which one to use you can either use some kind of dependency injection framework like spring or something. Or you could use the old school way to use a system property to decide which implementation to pick. Check your deploy environment for environment specific settings and use them for this.

(Also remind you testers that they need to test the real stuff also at one point or another....)